# Changing A Div To Select Input

Tags: jquery

I am having 2 Div Tag Set As Below

```
<div id="sortlocation" class="facetsearch">
    <div class="facetlist">
       <div id="facet_20" class="facetitem">Adambakkam <span class="facetitemcount">(15)</span></div>
       <div id="facet_12" class="facetitem">Ambattur <span class="facetitemcount">(59)</span></div>
       <div id="facet_17" class="facetitem">Anna Nagar <span class="facetitemcount">(18)</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

I need to convert the div which has the id newpar as a drop down menu (Select Menu). is that possible...

see this i have give an example that how i need [jsfiddle.net/varunms/WXK7S/5](http://jsfiddle.net/varunms/WXK7S/5)

Comment: when? if the user clicks, or on load or according to specific action?

Comment: hi there is no action is  needed

Comment: does it have any listeners associated with every item(div->option)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var s = $('<select />');
$('.facetlist .facetitem').each(function() {
   $('<option />', { 
       id: $(this).attr('id'), 
       'class': $(this).attr('class') 
   }).html($(this).text()).appendTo(s);
});
s.appendTo('body');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QzPrJ/)

Of course, the above is just a demo on how to create. For a proper replace, use jQuery `replaceWith`

```
$('.facetlist').replaceWith(s);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QzPrJ/1/)

Comment: I think he wants to replace the SortLocation div with the selectBox. So use the jquery replaceWith instead of appending it to the body.

Comment: @Yoeri: was adding it just as you commented :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

There are two parts to this:
1. get the options from the divs
This can be done with documnet.getElementsByClassName. you can then access the internals of each div easily enough.

1. create the selectbox
   You could either make an HTML string (yuck) or do something like this: 
   http://supunk.blogspot.com/2009/01/creating-select-list-using-javascript.html
2. Put the selectbox where you need it
   If you opted for the HTML string version you can set the sortlocation div's innerHTML

Comment: @Ronak Jangir's is quicker. I'm not big into jQuery